# rows that begin with a substring

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to find all the rows that have an `id` that starts with a '.' and some letters. When I call getElementsByIdStartsWith with this string, I get no rows returned, even though I can see (and inspect) them.

**Where is my error?**

```
getElementsByIdStartsWith: function (optionSymbolRoot) {
        var idArr = [];

        var trs = document.getElementById("tr");

        for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++)
        {   
            var s = trs[i].id;  
            if(true == s.startsWith(optionSymbolRoot))
                idArr.push(trs[i]);
        }

        return idArr;
    },     
ToggleRow : function(rootId) {

      var s = ".";
      var dottedSymbol = s.concat(rootId);
      //process.stdout.write(dottedSymbol);        

      var rows = this.getElementsByIdStartsWith(dottedSymbol);
      rows.forEach(function(row)
      {

        if (row.style.display == "") {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            row.style.display = "";
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: for starters, `document.getElementById` returns a single element that has the specified id. You're probably looking for [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: are you sure it's `getElementbyById` and not `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: `row.style.display` may have a number of values, so better to test for 'none' when toggling like: `row.style.display = row.style.display == 'none'? '' : 'none'`.

Comment: Gulp. Thanks that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getDocumentById` will only give one item, as the `ids` should be unique. If you want to get that kind of behavior I recommend the use of classes instead of ids or as stated in the comments above `getElementByTagName`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the querySelectorAll function

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id');
// This will return a NodeList with all elements that match the criteria.

function (optionSymbolRoot) {
    var idArr = [];

    var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

    for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++)
    {   
        var s = trs[i].className;  
        if(true == s.startsWith(optionSymbolRoot))
            idArr.push(trs[i]);
    }

    return idArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` gets a single element with the specified id attribute. To get all `<tr>` tags on a page, you can use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

//OR

var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
```

The second method is more flexible as it accepts any valid CSS selector, including tag names, `.classes` and `#ids`, but a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the selection with [`querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) and the "starts with"  [CSS3 attribute selector:](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) `attr^="str"`

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[id^="str"]')
```

The `NodeList` will need to be converted to an `Array`

```
function rowsIdStartsWith(optionSymbolRoot){
  var selector = 'tr[id^="' + optionSymbolRoot + '"]'
  var selected = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  return [].slice.call(selected)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ak3jxrLg/